# Dynamic URL service call in WP8 project

Tags: webservice-client

I have a problem with web server call in WP8 project. In my project in VS I added ServiceReferense (a web server gives me WSDL), VS created all classes and linked web calls to them, it has also stores login ans password for access. There is another web server, with same services and calls, set up on another URL. Sometimes I'll need to switch the web server i’m working with, but this requires to change login and password, now when I try to call the second one, I get error 401 (unautorized). How can I change login and password in automatically created ServiceRefferences?

I use VS 2013 and WP8.1 SDK. Project based on silverlight.